# How to improve skills in software architecture

Tags: architecture

I'm a python programmer, have worked with django/flask for more than 1 year. And wish to  improve skills in software architecture, see programming in a bigger picture. I've read , but found that not really help. Can someone give guideline? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two best videos from Neal Ford & Mark Richards (Orielly) on Software Architecture Fundamentals. These two videos are hosted by safaribooksonline.com

Software Architecture Fundamentals Part 1
Software Architecture Fundamentals Part 2

(Posted my comment as answer since I do not have enough points)